# How to pass PHP variable from drop down menu

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hello i am making `<select>` drop down menu and trying to make it so when someone clicks on one of the option of drop down it will open new window and at same time while clicking on option PHP variable of main page should pass to that new window

Could any one tell me where am i wrong, here's my code-

```
   <div class='fieldgroup'>
            <label for=@label>@label</label>
            <select name="@label" title="select optin" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;float: left;margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;height: 25px;">
                <option>@option1</option>
                <option <a href="#" onclick="window.open('@newwindow.php?@value=<?$@value?>','newWindow','width=800,height=600,left=150,top=200,toolbar=no,addressbar=yes,resizable=false');"></a>>@option2</option>
                <option>@optin3</option>
                <option>@optin3</option>
                <option>@option4</option>
                </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Psst, the syntax highlighter here should be a major clue as to where things might be going wrong for you.  You should also *always* quote your attributes, and should be making sure that characters used in names and ids are actually legal to use...

Comment: You may want to check into some jQuery handling as well as some Google Searching.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on what it really is: A HTML/Javascript problem. It has nothing to do with PHP. Try going step by step:

- Build a simple select in HTML.
- Then figure out how to open a window. You pretty much got that already.
- Then learn about [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It will make your Javascript developing much easier and more powerful in the future.
- Figure out, how to call an action when changing the selected value. ([Hint](http://api.jquery.com/change))
- Then (maybe in a new example) figure out how to read out an attribute when changing the select. ([Hint](http://api.jquery.com/attr/))
- Once you get there, put it all together, create your html code dynamically with PHP and you're all done.

This way you will learn a lot about how things work and what action happens in which world (HTML, Javascript, PHP).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an A tag inside an option, something like this should work:

```
<select onChange=" window.open('yoururl.php?value=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex]);">
```